# Proof that $(L^1)\neq(L^\infty)^\ast$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I have seen a "proof" that  $L^1\neq(L^\infty)^\ast$ which goes as follows:
show that there is an element of $(L^\infty)^\ast$ which is not in the image of the canonical map $L^1\rightarrow(L^\infty)^\ast$. From this they conclude that $(L^1)\neq(L^\infty)^\ast$, how does this follow? I mean simply because the canonical map is not an isomorphism it does not follow that they are not isomorphic (isometrically), isn't it? We must somehow distinguish them by properties (reflexive, separable etc) isn't it?

Comment: The "$=$" or "$\neq$" in $L^p = (L^q)^\ast$ or $L^p \neq (L^q)^\ast$ refers to the canonical map, not to the existence of any (isometric) isomorphism.

Comment: Yes.  For James space, we still have $J \ne J^{**}$ but the two are isometrically isomorphic.  The image of $J$ in $J^{**}$ has codimension $1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I see,  I find this notationally weird.

Comment: @DanielFischer: is this standard notation??

Comment: It's widely used. Normally, $=$ is used for equality, and then you have $L^p(X,\mu) \neq (L^q(X,\mu))^\ast$, since one is a space of equivalence classes of functions with domain $X$, while the other is a space of functions with domain $L^q(X,\mu)$, so they are different sets. One uses $=$ in some circumstances to denote not equality, but isomorphism under a very special map, here the natural injection of $L^p$ into $(L^q)^\ast$ if $p$ and $q$ are conjugate exponents. An arbitrary isometric isomorphism is something much weaker, so one doesn't use something as strong as $=$ for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We know that, $L_\infty$ is not separable, so neither does its dual $L_\infty^*$. It is remains to recall that $L_1$ is separable.

Comment: Thanks. By the way do you know whether they are isomorphic *as vector spaces*? (not isometrically)

Comment: @Loi: No, they're not isomorphic as vector spaces. The Hamel dimension of $L_1$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$ while the Hamel dimension of $L_\infty^*$ is $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

Comment: @user160629: thanks